# In C++ is there any portable way of jumping to a computed offset?

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a portable way of jumping to a computed offset in C++.

I know that GCC has a mechanism for doing this using goto as discussed here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/ec7e52b5-0978-4123-9d29-9dc7d807c6b4

Sadly I don't think other compilers implement this.

Normally I wouldn't have reason to use goto in C++ but I found that it could be useful for optimizing an interpreted language (search for 'threaded interpreter' if you are interested in this).

I know that I can implement this using inline assembly language, but the problem then is I have to implement this for every platform the interpreter runs on.

So does anyone know if there is a portable way of doing this?

The solution might involve goto but I'm open to any other sort of hackery that you can think of ;)

UPDATE: Currently the interpreter uses a switch statement.  I'm looking for techniques that improve on this and make the interpreter run faster.  Specifically I'm trying to figure out a portable way of saying 'goto <next-byte-code-instruction>' where <next-byte-code-instruction> is a computed offset that can be stored in the byte code itself.

UPDATE: I found a related question here. 
[What opcode dispatch strategies are used in efficient interpreters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511566/what-opcode-dispatch-strategies-are-used-in-efficient-interpreters)

Comment: There are many other ways to optimize such interpreters. For instance, take the common sequence "compare, branch-if-equal". Even the best optimized jump is slower than no jump at all. If you can fuse such common pairs of instructions, the C++ compiler also gets a chance to optimize variable access - e.g. the result of the "compare" instruction can stay in a register.

Comment: Yes there are plenty of other ways to optimize an interpreter, and I'm certainly not discounting them. I am sure I will use many different techniques - this question though is about a specific optimization.

Comment: one thing to keep in mind isthat even if such a (portable) mechanism exists (I don't think it does), there's little guarantee that it'll be faster, since it's pretty much cutting the compiler's optimizer entirely out of the loop. It's only able to optimize the code if it can *understand* the code. When you call a function, it knows where you're jumping from and to. When you jump to some computed offset, the compiler doesn't really have much of a chance to figure out where you might be jumping to, or what it means for the program flow, so it might inhibit optimizations.

Comment: Of course it doesn't guarantee that it'll be faster.  In theory it is though and others have already had success with it.  It is faster as it has less jumps than the normal loop & switch. Eg with loop & switch you pay for reading the instruction, then jumping to the handler & jumping back to the loop start.  With the threaded interpreter you read the instruction (also the offset of the code that handles the instruction) & jump direct to the handler, at the end of that read another instruction & jump direct to the next handler, and so on.

Comment: In summary the loop & switch mechanism needs: read, jump & jump per instruction & the threaded mechanism needs: read & jump per instruction. So in theory at least the threaded approach should be more efficient.

Comment: And its good enough for google (but they probably do it in assembly).

Answer (score 2):

1. `switch` allows to jump to predefined offsets
2. Array of function pointers/function objects
3. `setjmp`/`longjmp`

Comment: Switch statement is what I currently use & it is probably a good fallback for the code to be portable.  I already thought about an array of function ptrs but it means that you have to keep registers and parameters in global storage (as each byte code instruction executes in its own function) which complicates the interpreter not to mention has implications for multi-threading.  Also C/C++ compilers don't support tail recursion - if they did then function ptrs would be an attractive option for me.  I'll look into setjmp/longjmp, I remember Lua uses that for error handling, thanks for the idea.

Comment: You could keep your registers/parameters/conditions in a big State object that gets passed into and returned from the ops, like a monad. Or put it in thread local storage so it's "global" but not shared between threads.

Comment: I had a look into setjmp/longjmp.  It does look interesting and I just tried a simple test.  I stepped through the generated assembly code and discovered that longjmp uses quite a lot of instructions!  I don't think it will be faster than the switch statement.

Comment: @Ashley: C++ compilers often support tail recursion in simple cases. It's just nowhere near as robust as it is in functional languages.

Answer (score 1):

I think setjmp/longjmp is as close as you can get. Beyond that, the spec calls things like offsets in the instruction stream "implementation details", and you're stuck with platform-specific stuff like intrinsics and inline asm.

The other (really ugly) thing you could try is using a switch statement, which is typically implemented as a jump table of offsets.  Ie,

```
int ip = 0;

top:
switch( ip )
{
 case 0:
   ip += do_whatever(); // returns an offset
   goto top;
 case 1:
   ip += some_other_function();
   goto top;
 case 2:
   ip += etc();
   goto top;
  // ad infinitum...
}
```

This is in the spirit of Bell's original article, and the gist is that the body of each case is a single VM "opcode" in the stream. But that seems really icky.

Comment: The interpreter already uses a switch statement, sorry I should have made that clear in the question (I just updated it).

Answer (score 0):

Aside from goto's and longjumping and other nonportable tricks, could you consider virtual functions or at least ponters to functions? You can have several singleton objects of types derived from single base class. Array of pointers has all those objects. Virtual function returns index of the next interpreter state. Base object holds all data ever needed by any derived object.

EDIT: Pointers to functions could be a little faster even, but a little messier too. There is a [Guru of the Week article](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/057.htm) that explains it.

Comment: If I were to use virtual functions I'd have to implement a virtual class for every byte code.  This would waste too much time, and besides I'm trying to optimize it not make it slower ;)

Comment: I added a link to GotW article that could be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It was very interesting but I think it is an answer to a different question.  I do like its potential for finite state machines.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is not possible to implement this in a portable way.

(Although I still welcome alternative answers!)

I found this blog post from someone who has already tried what I wanted to do.  He uses the GCC approach and got a 33% speed improvement (stats are at the end of the post).

The solution is conditionally compiled under Win32 to use inline assembly to compute the address of the labels.  But he reports that using inline assembly in this way is 3 times slower than normal!  Ouch

http://abepralle.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/how-not-to-make-a-virtual-machine-label-based-threading/

Oh well, I didn't want to use inline assembly anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I seriously wouldn't use any form of goto. It died a long time ago. If you must, however, perhaps you should just write a macro for this, and use a bunch of ifdefs to make it portable. This shouldn't be too hard, and it is the fastest solution.

Comment: Like I said I wouldn't normally use goto.  And I actually think this is one of the rare cases that the use of goto looks like a good idea, but unfortunately most compilers don't even do what I want anyway. Ultimately I will probably have to resort to inline assembly and macros (with a fallback to the switch statement to make it portable).  Although I am just hoping someone will provide an innovative answer that I haven't heard of before ;)

Comment: The ides that goto had died a long time ago has itself died a long time ago. While it is true that goto can be abused to create spaghetti code, it can also be used to write cleaner, more concise code. Like any tool in the hands of a worker, it can be used for good or evil, and it is the worker to blame for his creation, not the tool.